# plus two huge string number

Tags: php, numbers

PHP

```
$SCode=$_POST['SCode'];
$ECode=$_POST['ECode'];

for($p=$SCode;$p<($ECode - $SCode);$p++)
{

    $hugePluse1 =sprintf('%0.0f',$p+$SCode);
    $hugePluse2 = $p+$SCode ;
    echo  $hugePluse1.",".$hugePluse2."<br/>";
}
```

i run this with

```
$_POST['SCode']='010100100101002084';
$_POST['ECode']='010100100101002087';
```

but this does not worked.

$hugePluse1 return ==>10100100101002084,10100100101002084,10100100101002086,10100100101002088

and

$hugePluse2 return ==>1.0100100101002E+16,1.0100100101002E+16,1.0100100101002E+16,1.0100100101002E+16

i want `010100100101002084`,`010100100101002085`,`010100100101002086`

please help me

Comment: Are those octal numbers?

Comment: You might just have to convert numbers to strings. What you want will have to be string values because of the leading zero, but being you're doing arithmetic, you're gonna get doubles back.

Comment: @JohnConde yes octal number

Comment: It should not be octal number.Octal number don't have 8

Comment: Consider using the BCMath extension, it's made for these things: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a function that I made for you.
It will sum up two string and returns the string.

```
function string_sum($a,$b,$base)
{
    $a=strrev($a);
    $b=strrev($b);
    $result="";
    $carry=0;

    for($i=0;$i<max(strlen($a),strlen($b));$i++)
    {
        $x=$y=0;
        if($i<strlen($a))
        {
            $x=substr($a,$i,1);
        }
        if($i<strlen($b))
        {
            $y=substr($b,$i,1);
        }
        $sum=$x+$y+$carry;
        $result=$sum%$base.$result;
        $carry= intval($sum/$base);
    }
    if($carry)
    {
        $result=$carry.$result;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

This function takes 3 parameter.
First two the string number and third one the base,10 for decimal numbers
If you call this

```
string_sum('010100100101002084',1,10);
```

it will return

```
'010100100101002085'
```

hope you understand.

Comment: While it's quite impressive that you've made a function to do addition in primary-school style, there are some things wrong with it (support for bases, but only base-10 or less - also, base-1 would give interesting results), not to mention it's completely redundant because BCMath exists.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol When I read the comments it says the number is octal that's why I wrote the function.Primary education is best eduction which teach you the basic.

Comment: An octal number ending in `84`. I see.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol Did you read my comments at the question?OP says its octal. That's why I wrote the function in-case he need octal. But the number he puts as example is not octal.